# Why does vim indent in my html files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I have this

```
<p>
  <b>Author_id:</b>
  <%= @entry.author %>
</p>_
```

(Note that '_' is where my cursor is at currently)

When I press enter

vim indents my file with the following:

```
<p>
  <b>Author_id:</b>
  <%= @entry.author %>
  </p>
```

Which is super annoying. What feature is this? How do I stop this behaviour?

BTW I am using .html.erb

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `'autoindent'`.

Call...

```
:verbose set autoindent?
```

...to see from where it was set and...

```
:set noautoindent
```

...to reset it.

See also:

- [`:help :set`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%3aset)
- [`:help 'autoindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoindent%27)
- [`:help 'cindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cindent%27)
- [`:help 'smartindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartindent%27)
- [`:help :verbose-cmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3averbose-cmd)

Comment: I have "Last set from ~/.vimrc". In my .vimrc I have `set autoindent` . Does that help you?

Comment: Then you should change your `~/.vimrc` to have `set noautoindent` instead. Or just remove it, since it defaults to off.

Comment: @disappearedng: Do my comment (and updated answer) help *you*?